# C++ atoi returning incorrect values

Tags: c++, atoi

> The problem seems fixed now, thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2609288/baldrick for his response, he pointed out the main issue that led me to think atoi was returning the wrong value.
>   Since I was printing the results into a console window using AllocConsole, I guess cout was printing the results incorrectly, after printing a few integers with high values, this does indeed seem to be the case.

so I searched around before asking this and I can't seem to find anyone with a similar case to mine, so I'll ask here.

I have a config file, which contains ids that aren't in incremental order, example:

```
48|0:0:0.001:0
49|0:0:0.001:0
59|0:0:0.001:0
60|497:0:0.001:0
61|504:0:0.001:1
63|0:0:0.001:0
500|0:0:0.001:0
505|0:0:0.001:0
506|0:0:0.001:0
507|0:0:0.001:0
508|0:0:0.001:0
509|0:0:0.001:0
512|0:0:0.001:0
515|0:0:0.001:0
516|0:0:0.001:0
517|415:132:0.001:1
```

Now, the issue is raised when ever I attempt to read these values from a file, and parse them to an int using atoi, when I convert it to an int, 517 would become 202 or some random number like that, is this normal behavior? Here's an example of how I'm parsing the file and converting the ID's:

```
std::vector<std::string> x = split(line, '|');
int id = atoi(x[0].c_str());
cout << id << " ";
std::vector<std::string> x2 = split(line, ':');
int kit = atoi(x2[0].c_str());
cout << kit << " ";
int seed = atoi(x2[1].c_str());
cout << seed << " ";
int wear = atoi(x2[2].c_str());
cout << wear << " ";
int stat = atoi(x2[3].c_str());
cout << stat << endl;
this->ParseSkin(id, kit, seed, wear, stat);
```

Would using atoi in this case be incorrect?

Comment: Are you sure `split` is working correctly?  If you just print out `x[0]` is it correct?

Comment: It's working as intended, I've printed the raw split values without using atoi and they're all correct and match the files contents.

Comment: This is why we require MCVEs....

Comment: you are using atoi() on a decimal number! (wear)

Comment: Also, you're resplitting the same line with `:`, so `x2[0]` will contain "48|0". This isn't a valid input to `atoi`. Should be `x[1]` you are splitting the second time.

Comment: the id is incorrect, but thanks for pointing that out, fixed that part now :P

Comment: *"ids that aren't in incremental order"* - They seem to be in incremental order in your example.

Comment: tl;dr `atoi` is never correct, use `std::stoi` to be able to handle errors and allow "0".

Comment: @Baldrick thanks for pointing that out, initial error is still present.

Comment: @ChristianHackl exactly the same problem, logged the values and this is the result for 517: 517 -> 205
`cout << x[0].c_str() << " -> " << std::stoi(x[0].c_str()) << endl;`

Comment: @Lynxaa: There is an error in the code you don't show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trouble is you're resplitting the same `line` variable with `:`, so `x2[0]` will contain "48|0". This isn't a valid input to `atoi`.

Try this instead:

```
std::vector<std::string> x = split(line, '|');
int id = atoi(x[0].c_str());
cout << id << " ";
std::vector<std::string> x2 = split(x[1], ':');
int kit = atoi(x2[0].c_str());
```

This should work better, as you're passing a valid input to `split` the second time round.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtol` instead of `atoi`. It can stop at any non-digit char. Try this:

```
char * str = line;
id = strtol( str, &str, 10 ); str++;
kit = strtol( str, &str, 10 ); str++;
seed = strtol( str, &str, 10 ); str++;
wear = strtol( str, &str, 10 ); str++;
stat = strtol( str, &str, 10 );
```

Comment: same result, 517 -> 205

Comment: @Lynxaa Without `split`? `strtol` does similar like split with 2nd parameter.

Comment: @Lynxaa :) I never use `cin` and `cout` but people don't get this advice.

Comment: woops deleted by mistake, "seems to be fixed, never trust cout"